# Proving that a function is negligible

Tags: semantic-security, negligible

My question is about proving that a function is negligible if it is ran polynomial number of times.

> [image: question]

**This my solution**: By the definition of negligibility, we have $negl_1(n) < 1/p'(n)$ where $p'(n)$ is any polynomial. We multiply $p(n)$ both sides: $p(n)*negl_1(n) < p(n)/p'(n)$.

We let $p'(n)>>p(n)$. There is always a $p'(n)$ that satisfies this inequality. Thus, $negl_2(n) = p(n)*negl_1(n)$ is negligible.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You showed that there exists some polynomial function p', instead what you're looking for is to show that for any polynomial function p', then negl is smaller

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not correct. You have to show that $\mathbf{\text{negl}_2}$ satisfies the definition of negligible functions and what you "showed" actually is that given any sufficiently large polynomial $p'(n)$, it holds that  $\mathbf{\text{negl}_2} < \frac{p(n)}{p'(n)}$.

I see two easy ways of solving that exercise:

- Try to prove it by contradiction supposing that $\mathbf{\text{negl}_2}$ is not negligible and then finding a polynomial whose inverse is asymptotically smaller than $\mathbf{\text{negl}_1}$.
- Try to prove it directly: from any given polynomial $p'(n)$, you know that $p(n)p'(n)$ is a polynomial, therefore,  $\mathbf{\text{negl}_1}$ must be smaller than $1 / (p(n)p'(n))$ for all $n$ bigger than some $n_0$...

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to solve this and I'll be happy if someone would be able to say it's correct or not.

Let p be a positive polynomial.
Since $negl_1$ is negligible there's a number N such that for any n>N we have:
$$negl_1(n) < \frac{1}{p(n) * p(n)}$$

(as polynomial * polynomial is polynomial)

This gives us that for any n>N we have:

$$negl_2(n) = p(n) * negl_1(n) < p(n) * \frac{1}{p(n) * p(n)} = \frac{1}{p(n)}$$

And we got that $negl_2$ is a negligible function as well.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.Se We have $\LaTeX$/ mathJax enabled in our site.

Comment: Thanks, edited :)

Comment: You cannot assume a factorization of the type $p(n) p(n)$ or even $p(n) p'(n)$ with nonconstant polynomials on the right hand side of your first equation.

Comment: It's not a factorization, it's a new polynomial made of multiplication of two polynomial

Comment: all you can assume when a function is negligible is that there is some nonconstant growing polynomial, not that there is a polynomial growing fast enough that it is growing faster than the product of two nonconstant polynomial. so you are assuming what you want to prove